# Azure No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, cors, cross-domain

I have a .NET Core web app which I host in Azure Web Apps. One of it's function is to parse XML feeds server side.

The logic worked up until recently the RSS feeds stop returning data when called via C#. You can see the RSS feed when accessed through the browser.

**The problem**

The solution now only works on localhost. If I call the RSS feeds directly using AJAX, I get this error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://blah.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

From what I understand, the server has not included the header in the response?

But then how does this website https://codebeautify.org/rssviewer manage to return the RSS feed?

**Javascript**

```
var data = [
    { title: "UK", Url: "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml" },
    { title: "World", Url: "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml" }
];

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    url: "api/xml",
    success: (data) => {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

**C#**

```
public MyResponse Get(List<MyRequest> requests)
{
    foreach(var request in requests)
    {
        request.XDocument = XDocument.Load(request.Url);
    }

    return new MyResponse(requests);
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled CORS on your Azure Web App? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api#add-cors-functionality

Comment: @softbear why would I do that? Isn't the issue the response from where I'm getting the RSS feed i.e. BBC?

Comment: *“From what I understand, the server has not included the header in the response?”* ⬅ Yes. *“But then how does this website https://codebeautify.org/rssviewer manage to return the RSS feed?”* That site must be making the request for that RSS feed from its backend server-side code rather than from its frontend JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the POST data was not received by my controller when the code was deployed to Azure. Not sure why, but I was able to see this by setting up Remote Debugging following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio.

When following this guide, I did encounter an issue with my Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition not being able to locate Internet Explorer.

Basically, Visual Studio is looking for iexplore.exe, which for some reason, I did not have (maybe because Edge is present?). I'm running Windows 10 Home, version 10.0.17134.

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App
>   Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE

To resolve this this, I installed Internet Explorer 11.

1. Press Windows Key
2. Search manage optional features
3. Click Add a feature
4. Find Internet Explorer
5. Install, reboot to finish installation

I didn't figure why the POST data wasn't received, but as a temporary workaround, I didn't need to send the data from JS, so I moved the data to the controller in the meantime.